# New example duplicates in documents when clicked the plus mark

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-topics

When I click the plus button with 'Add Example' in the documentation section it opened two instances of examples. Though it wasn't noticeable at the creation but when you going to submit a draft an error is thrown from the empty example.

[image: Duplication issue with Add example buttong]

Should it be fixed?

Comment: Well, it seems this issue has been fixed now.